# Indexing a dataframe column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

How can I index values in a column in pandas and make it into a new column? This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Original:

       Data    
0  0010-AAAA    
1  0010-BBBB    
2  0010-CCCC    
3  0011-DDDD    
4  0011-EEEE    

Adding two columns:
       Data    col_2   col_3  
0  0010-AAAA    0010    AAAA
1  0010-BBBB    0010    BBBB
2  0010-CCCC    0010    CCCC
3  0011-DDDD    0011    DDDD
4  0011-EEEE    0011    EEEE
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['col_2', 'col_3']] = df['Data'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
```

output:

```
        Data col_2 col_3
0  0010-AAAA  0010  AAAA
1  0010-BBBB  0010  BBBB
2  0010-CCCC  0010  CCCC
3  0011-DDDD  0011  DDDD
4  0011-EEEE  0011  EEEE
```

##### no dash

Then use a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extrcat.html).

In this case: numbers `\d+`, followed by non numbers `\D+`:

```
df[['col_2', 'col_3']] = df['Data'].str.extract(r'(\d+)(\D+)')
```

output:

```
       Data col_2 col_3
0  0010AAAA  0010  AAAA
1  0010BBBB  0010  BBBB
2  0010CCCC  0010  CCCC
3  0011DDDD  0011  DDDD
4  0011EEEE  0011  EEEE
```

or even: `r'(\d+)\W*(\D+)'` (digits / optional non-alphanum / non-digits) to handle both cases at once:

```
df[['col_2', 'col_3']] = df['Data'].str.extract(r'(\d+)\W*(\D+)')
```

example:

```
        Data col_2 col_3
0  0010-AAAA  0010  AAAA
1   0010BBBB  0010  BBBB
2  0010-CCCC  0010  CCCC
3   0011DDDD  0011  DDDD
4  0011-EEEE  0011  EEEE
```

Comment: Thanks. If the Data column doesn't have a '-' (ie. 0010AAAA instead of 0010-AAAA) how would you split them?

Comment: Then I would use a regex, see update

Comment: Is there a way to do it with just index numbers? If for example I would want to split the first column to have the first 6 values and the second column to have the last 2

Comment: Yes: `df['col_2'] = df['Data'].str[:4]` and `df['col_3'] = df['Data'].str[5:]`, but this is less efficient and robust IMO

Comment: Did it work as you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['col_2','col_3']]= df['Data'].str.split("-",expand=True)
df
```

```
Data    col_2   col_3
0   0010-AAAA   0010    AAAA
1   0010-BBBB   0010    BBBB
2   0010-CCCC   0010    CCCC
3   0011-DDDD   0011    DDDD
4   0011-EEEE   0011    EEEE
```

Comment: If the Data column doesn't have a '-' (ie. 0010AAAA instead of 0010-AAAA) how would you split them?

Answer (score 0):

All the python string methods will work, including slicing

```
df["Data"].str[:4]

0    0010
1    0010
2    0010
3    0011
4    0011
```